# Sum of powers of 2 is separate power included

Tags: math

So, we have some number, which is sum of powers of 2:

for example `308 = 256 + 32 + 16 + 4`

Is there a way to know, is separate power of 2 included in this sum?

For example, 32 (2 in power of 5) is included.

But 8 (2 in power of 3) is not.

Is there some formula for this?

Comment: Sure, I know, that can be done via bitwise AND. But can it be expressed via math formula?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "formula"? What's the problem with using bitwise AND?

Comment: I mean math or algorithm formula, not bitwise operator. It's not a problem to use it, but it should also an other way.

Comment: That explains nothing. What is "math or algorithm formula" and why can't it use a bitwise operator? What operations can it use?

Comment: Ok, 2+2 =4 is math formula. I don't want to use bitwise operator for this case.

Comment: It seems to me like you don't know what your question means yourself. In any case, if you don't bother to explain what you actually mean, don't expect useful answers.

Comment: What is unclear? I want to use formula something like provided by blazs ("k == i && n % 2 == 0") and NOT bitwise operator. How can I explain it in other words? I didn't deserve that minus actually.

Comment: So how is using `%` different from using `&`? How do I know which operators you are allowing me to use? What blazs gave is actually a lot further from a mathematical formula because it contains a loop and a conditional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107738/discussion-between-goltsev-eugene-and-interjay).

Comment: What is your primary problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Simply check

```
if (n & (1 << i)) {
   it is included
}
```

where `(1 << i)` means `2^i`.

In your particular case you'd check with `if (308 & (1 << 5)) { /* ... */ }` because `32=2^5`.

I've now read the belatedly added comment. I don't think there's a representation-independent formula (by which I mean a [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)).

There's of course the obvious algorithm to check whether `2^i` is "included" in the number, where included means "the number `2^i` has to appear if we want to write `n` as a sum of powers of two". (Note that this is essentially computing binary representation of `n`, which is *already* represented in binary in the computer.)

```
int k = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    if (k == i && n % 2 == 0) {
        /* contained */
    }
    k++;
    n /= 2;
}
```

Comment: is a cycle or bitwise operation the only way to determine this?

Comment: In the absence of additional assumptions, I don't currently see a faster way. If you assume that `n` comes from a  finite range, you can use a data structure to speed things up.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the bitwise approach (which is the best)?

Comment: I just want to know all possible ways

Comment: If you want to avoid bitwise operations you can do `floor(n/(2^i)) % 2 == 1` will give the same result as `n & (1 << i)`. But the bitwise option as suggested by Blaze is clearly superior, I don't see any reason not to use it.

Comment: @pseudoDust, that's what I wanted, thanks. Pls put this as an answer and I'll mark it as a right one.

Comment: @GoltsevEugene To any other person Blazs's answer will be more useful so you might as well mark their answer as correct.